How do i keep my border for a video consistent when it resizes?
I have a webpage with a  tag.  There is a border around it, but when the video resizes for any reason, like grabbing the edge of the page and shrinking it, the video shrinks in size, but the border does not and leaves empty space between itself and the video.  Does anyone know a way to fix this?
My video tag looks like this by the way.
html:
<video height="400" width="500" controls>
    <source src="myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

css:
video {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: thick solid #000;
}

I tried changing the padding and margin, but had no luck.
I also tried border-sizing: border-box, and I tried content-box.  I don't exactly know how those work but I researched and thought they would. It didn't do anything.
I also tried to remove the display: block; and the max-width: 100%; but still nothing, not even something different breaking.

Standard video aspect ratio is 16:9. The aspect ratio of your current video element is 5:4 (500px x 400px). Remove the height and leave the width and the height will automatically conform to the video's width with an aspect ratio of 16:9 (or 4:3 if it's an older video).
In the example below the first video is configured as width: 500px and height: 400px. The second video has only width: 500px.


video {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border: thick solid #000;
}
<video width="500" height="400" src="https://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/av/vs8s3.mp4" controls></video>

<video width="500" src="https://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/av/vs8s3.mp4" controls></video>



